# Отправка post запроса не зная некоторые данные (Python3, requests)

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь пройти авторизацию на сайте с помощью отправки POST запроса, но я не знаю некоторые данные для этого. Возможно ли создать такой запрос?

```
import requests

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0',
    }
)
s = requests.Session()
s = requests.post(
    "http://site.com",
    data={
        "username": myusername,
        "password": mypassword,
        "autologin": "on",
        "redirect": "index.php",
        "creation_time": None,
        "form_token": None,
        "sid": None,
        "login:": "Вход",
    },
    headers=headers
)
print(s.text)
```

Comment: Что значит "не знаю некторые данные"?

Comment: Я написал их как None, я смотрю POST запрос который делает сайт при авторизации и там есть такие пункты как creation_time, form_token и sid, я не знаю как их получить, они всегда разные. Заранее извиняюсь, если долблюсь в глаза.

Comment: "они всегда разные" вероятно используется яваскрипт, запрос без указания этих параметров вызывает ошибку? (то есть просто проигнарируй их не указывая их в словаре)

Comment: Да, без указания в словаре (или указывая, как в коде выше) вылетает ошибка Ajax: `<div id="darkenwrapper" class="darkenwrapper" data-ajax-error-title="Ошибка AJAX" data-ajax-error-text="При обработке запроса произошла ошибка." data-ajax-error-text-abort="Запрос прерван пользователем." data-ajax-error-text-timeout="Время запроса истекло; повторите попытку." data-ajax-error-text-parsererror="При выполнении запроса возникла непредвиденная ошибка, и сервер вернул неверный ответ."> <div id="darken" class="darken">&nbsp;</div>`

Comment: попробуйте сначало отправить get и получить текст сайта и найти там creation_time, form_token и sid также эти данные могут хранится в куки. Я могу предположить что creation_time это восколько был создан аккаунт.